# "The package System.Net.Http with version 4.1.1 could not be found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\."

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, nuget

I am trying to evaluate a software SDK for displaying PDF files. It comes with a few sample projects, but I am having problems building the C++ projects. I am pretty sure this is a problem with my local environment, but I have no idea how to fix it:

The projects come as a Visual Studio solution, to be used in Visual Studio 2017. Upon first opening it I was told to install missing features (VS17 was a plain install with no workloads before):

[image: Install Universal Windows Platform development and C++ universal Windows Platform tools]

After installing that, and twiddling with platform toolset and the general platform target settings, I could finally build the C++ library part that creates a `.dll` file to be used by the other 2 C++ projects. (I could also confirm that this works fine, as the also included C# project used the library perfectly fine.)

---

But for the 2 remaining C++ projects I get this error on build:

```
The package System.Net.Http with version 4.1.1 could not be found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\. Run a NuGet package restore to download the package. 
FunctionDemo    
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\15.0\Microsoft.NuGet.targets  
377
```

Unfortunately I have no idea what "Use NuGet Package Restore to download them." means in that context - both the solution and all the projects have nothing listed when using `Manage NuGet Packages...` in Visual Studio. So I don't even know where this dependency comes from. (Are those part of the general SDKs I have installed maybe?)

---

Double clicking the error message opens `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\15.0\Microsoft.NuGet.targets` with this:

```
<ResolveNuGetPackageAssets Condition="Exists('$(FrameworkInjectionLockFile)')"
                           NuGetPackagesDirectory="$(FrameworkInjectionPackagesDirectory)"
                           RuntimeIdentifier="$(NuGetRuntimeIdentifier)"
                           TargetMonikers="$(NuGetTargetMonikerToInject)"
                           ProjectLockFile="$(FrameworkInjectionLockFile)">
```

But I guess this is pretty standard. Does this tell me something where the error comes from?

---

On the filesystem `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\System.Net.Http\4.1.1` indeed does not exist. Any tries to fill it manually (download the nuget package manually to a project, and copying the results here, using any solutions or commands to run I can find online) failed.

---

If found out that `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\` is the package source `Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages` which I can view via Options -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Sources in Visual Studio 2017, but disabling it there didn't change anything about the error message.

---

Am I looking in the wrong place?
Is this really my local problem or a project problem?
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Please let me know here if I need to add any other information or data about the solution or projects. Visual Studio and C++ are not really my thing, so I might have missed the most obvious information.

Answer (score 1):

I "fixed" this by getting the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\System.Net.Http\4.1.1` folder from another developer. Then the error message switched to other packages, so in the end he sent me his full `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages` and I copied folders over until it finally built.

Still not idea what caused this, must have been a missing payload or SDK that Visual Studio thinks was installed but really wasn't :/

Keeping the question unanswered though in the hopes that someone comes along that know the *real* fix.

Comment: Hi janpio, we are so glad to hear that your issue is solved, please mark your reply as answer when you have free time and that will help other community members to easier search it, thanks in advance :)

Comment: As I wrote, this is not solved - I had to copy stuff from another developer's computer into my `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages` which feels _very_ wrong and probably put hundreds of unneeded and broken folders in there. There should be a real solution that _solves_ the problem, not works around it.

Comment: Hi janpio, sorry for my misunderstanding and thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me after upgrading from Visual Studio 2017 to 2019. While not the same file, my error was:

> error APPX0702: Payload file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\NuGetPackages\System.Private.ServiceModel\4.1.3\runtimes\win7\lib\netcore50\System.Private.ServiceModel.dll'
>   does not exist.

For whatever reason, after upgrading, both VS 2017 and VS 2019 were looking for this in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages..., but I found it actually existed in the similarly named folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\UWPNuGetPackages... instead. I assume during the installation of VS 2019 this directory was created?

I manually copied the files over to where it was looking and then the build finally worked. The underlying issue isn't fixed, but maybe somebody smarter than me can explain why this happened in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

For me disabling `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\` didn't work either. But then I had deleted it from `Nuget.Config` and it had finally solved the problem.